Apache Reverse Proxy - prevent AutoSSL from following redirects in Apache includes?
I have a cPanel server in which I wrote an include config file with a reverse proxy to point it to a react application hosted on the server.
Here is an example:
 ServerName my.website

ProxyRequests off

<Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
</Proxy>

<Location />
        ProxyPass http://localhost:8080/
        ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8080/
</Location>

My server uses Let's Encrypt AutoSSL to secure the domain, but the configuration file causes redirection issues, preventing AutoSSL from securing the domain. I've attempted various exemptions to bypass the DCV file, but none have been successful so far. How can I write it so that it AutoSSL will continue to secure my domain, even with the reverse proxy in place.
